# Joining true date to text date in SAS/proc sql

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I need to join on ~today (or an arbitrary date in the past for checking)
to a large lake based table using SAS/proc sql. I'm struggling because the lake table uses hardcoded text columns for dates. I initially wanted to reformat the text date as a date date but realised this would involve dealing with unnecessarily large amounts of data.

Looking at the information available there seems to be a lot of processes to change text to a date but not to change a formatted date to true text (when I use the put function it turns 2024-02-02 date into 2020 numeric).

Does anyone have any advice on how to look for further information?

Thanks

Put didn't work
Cats worked but requires a macro to fill 0s. Feels like that's overkill?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Do you mean to say the values of the variable is a string?  If so use INPUT() with an appropriate informat to convert the string to an actual date value.  Then you can filter using any date logic.  If you want the dates printed in a way that you find easier for humans to read then attach an appropriate date format to the resulting numeric variable.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand what you are asking but this statement is false:

> when I use the put function it turns 2024-02-02 date into 2020 numeric

When you use the PUT() or PUTN() function to format a numeric variable the result is always a character string.  The PUT() function converts values into text.  The input() function converts text into values.

Perhaps you made the mistake of trying to use 2020-02-03 in SAS code without wrapping it in quotes to let SAS know you meant a string literal.  In that case you asked SAS to subtract 2 and 3 from 2020.  Just like if you wrote 2+2 SAS would add them to get 4.

If you want to write a date constant in your code you can use a date literal.  Which is a string that the DATE informat can understand enclosed in quotes and followed immediately by the letter D.  So `'03FEB2020'd` for example.  Or you could just write the unformatted number of days since 1960 that SAS uses to represent dates. The number `21948` would be third day of the second month of the year 2020.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Apologies I've been dealing with this issue at work so I am unable to provide any meaningful code/log. 

Essentially you've hit the nail on the head. I don't understand why:

call symput('x',put(date)) returns a date

but

x = date as numeric

So as I understand it I can't call it in the same way I can other variables. I could insert it into the table (I figured that part out) but the formatting not retained for other purposes?

Thanks again for your help. I am working on a way of getting SAS outside of my work comp.

Comment: Macro variables only contain text. It is how you use them to generate code that might make the text look like a number to SAS.  There is no need to format a date value you put into macro variable that is going to be used to filter data, it does not need to look good to humans.  So putting the five digit string `21948` will work fine.  PS Don't use the ancient CALL SYMPUT() function.  Use the modern CALL SYMPUTX() instead.